# Play video on BOOT, not logon

Tags: raspbian, boot, video, omxplayer, lxterminal

I have tried many tutorials but can't get this to work. I simply want to play a video when my Pi turns on.

**This is not when I LOG IN, or when the desktop starts, but a second or two after I plug in my Pi**.

I know it works as I have seen it on tutorials but they never work.

I have tried:
- editing rc.local
- adding script to init.d and insserv
- something else which involves a "Desktop Entry"

And it just won't work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Raspbian is Debian and your script must be LSB Compliant. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Comment: That's not the problem here -- `/etc/rc.local` doesn't have to be LSB compliant.  The problem is that running a foreground graphical app via init is more complicated than running, e.g., a background service.   Also, Debian/Raspbian users might as well learn to use systemd instead now, since SysV has been abandoned (although `init.d` scripts are still supported for backward compatibility).